# Showing the Existence of a Quadratic Residue

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Given that $$x^{(p-1)/2} \equiv {1 \bmod p}$$, then $x$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.  I'm having a hard time showing this though, because even though it's clear that $q = x^{(p+1)/4}$ has the property that $q^2 \equiv x \bmod p$, it's not obvious to be that $q$ exists because $(p+1)/4$ isn't always integral.  How can I go about showing that $x$ is a quadratic residue in this case?

Comment: do you know that $\mathbb F^*_p$ is a cyclic group?

Comment: It follows directly from [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion). If $p$ is an odd prime, then $x^{(p-1)/2}\equiv \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\pmod{p}$ for all $x\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $x$ be a *fixed number* such that $x^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. We will show that $x$ is a quadratic residue of $p$, using only Wilson's Theorem.

For any $s$ and $t$ between $1$ and $p-1$ we say that $t$ is a **friend** of $s$ if $st\equiv x\pmod{p}$. It is clear that for every $s$ between $1$ and $p-1$, there is a unique $t$ such that $t$ is a friend of $s$.

We want to show that there is an $s$ such that $s$ is her own friend, that is, $s^2\equiv x\pmod{p}$.

Suppose to the contrary that no one is her own friend. Pair the numbers between $1$ and $p-1$ into groups of $2$ friends. Since the product of the numbers in any friend pair is congruent to $x$, it follows that the product of all the numbers between $1$ and $p-1$, that is, $(p-1)!$, is congruent to $x^{(p-1)/2}$ modulo $p$.

We were told that $x^{(p-1)/2}$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$. However, by Wilson's Theorem, $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. This contradiction shows that someone must be her own friend.

*Remark:* If we already know that every prime has a primitive root $g$, we can give a simpler proof. We want to show that $x$ is congruent to an even power of $g$. If to the contrary $x\equiv g^k$ where $k$ is odd, then $g^{k(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, which can be shown to contradict the fact that $g$ has order $p-1$ modulo $p$.